# Is there a Task.Run equivalent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, multithreading

In C# there is the Task.Run(() => {}) method which makes it easy to run code asynchronously. Is there an equivalent method in JavaScript?

So far, the closes I've gotten is [nested usage of *setTimeout* like this:](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval#nested-settimeout)

```
setTimeout(async function logStatus() {
    const result = await someNetworkCall();
    console.log(result);
    setTimeout(() => {
      logStatus();
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);
```

The above code simply calls a network service once a second and logs the result to the console. However, I'm worried about getting an eventual stackoverflow exception due to the recursive way of letting the *logStatus* method call *logStatus* from within itself.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't know much about JS, but as far as I know it is single-threaded by design. The closest thing to Tasks would be promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Side note: `Task.Run` is for running code in parallel (not "to run code asynchronously")... If you really would be asking what you wrote you would be looking for WebWorkers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm by no stretch of the imagination a JS expert (or even proficient in JS), you should he able to use immediately-invoked Function Expressions and the fact that promises are always immediately executed to do achieve this, something like

```js
// we want/ need a promise based sleep function
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// now our actual continuously running function
// this is a IIFE: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-iife/
(async () => {
    while (true) {
        const result = await someNetworkCall();
        console.log(result);
        await sleep(1000);
    }
})()
```

You'll probably want to implement something so you can cancel that `while (true)` loop, but I'll leave that up to you

The equivalent to `Task.Run(async () => ... )` would be `(async () => ... )()` as far as I can tell, and the equivalent to a C# `Task` is a `Promise`

I created a jsfiddle you can run in your browser demonstrating the core concept [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v0fqo7rw/) (don't worry, I replaced the while true loop with a for loop that goes to 10 so it actually stops running)